# how can i use python script in vb.net?

Tags: python, vb.net

How can i use python script in vb.net because i'm using vb.net for gui

I found one solution

> Shell ("C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\python.exe myPath\PythonScript.py arg1 arg2")

But how can i fetch output from shell to in to my vb.net GUI?

Comment: Don't use `Shell` in VB.NET.  Use `Process.Start` regardless, but doing so does allow you to redirect the standard output stream to retrieve process output. Now that you have those keywords, you can search for examples, of which there will be plenty.